# Is it possible to use PHP on a website hosted on AWS S3 without using EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, elastic-beanstalk

I have a bit of PHP (a contact form to be exact) that isn't working right now on my website. I'd like to activate the PHP and I heard one of the ways is to use Elastic Beanstalk. However, Elastic Beanstalk engages EC2 which can be costly. I'd like to know if there are ways to activate this PHP without using EC2.

Comment: As ceejayoz said, S3 is static content only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 is a storage service. Code of any sort will not execute on it.

There are cheaper options than AWS if you just want to run a tiny, non-critical contact form script. Shared hosting might run you as low as a buck a month, or a small Digital Ocean instance runs $5/month.

If your current website has PHP support and it's still not working, though, you're likely to need to fix the script, not change servers.